# Whole disk unallocated? Gparted error or partition overlapping?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, fdisk

Story:

Yesterday I wanted to make my Ubuntu partition bigger so I ran Windows (Dual boot) and decreased size of my D drive size. It wanted me to reboot computer, when it was starting up it done everything and rebooted once again. Then I saw grub rescue with "no filesystem" or something like that. I ran Ubuntu live CD to fix that and it is now working.

Problem:

Problem is when I want to add unallocated part of HDD to my Ubuntu partition I can't, because GParted thinks whole disk is unallocated! I tried fixing filesystem by: `fsck /dev/sda5 -f -r`, but I think that's not it (or I'm doing it wrong way). I have also tried `chkdsk` from Windows Installation CD, but it didn't fix anything. Also, both of systems **are** working.

Is it just GParted problem, or maybe HDD is bad for real? If so, how to fix it?

`fdisk -l` can see partitions:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa118d672

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   286719999   143256576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       286720000   811972349   262626175    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       915726335   976771071    30522368+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       915726336   968652799    26463232   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       968652800   976771071     4059136   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Images:
[image]
[image: This is about partiton]

Comment: @psusi Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/557831/gparted-problems-with-swap-and-extended-partition). There is a `fdsik -l` output before doing anything with partition table and after.